# sum numeric variable six months ago

Tags: r, date, lubridate

i have a data base with dates and numeric variables. I also have multiple rows per id. It looks like this:

| ID | date | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 | 3 |
| 1 | 2018-12-01 | 4 |
| 1 | 2017-11-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2017-10-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 2017-09-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 2017-08-01 | 2 |

I need to sum x up to six month ago from date, so i tried this

```
library(lubridate)
    mutate(semester= semester(fecha_inicio,with_year = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(ID,semester) %>%
  mutate(sum_semester = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

but is not what i need because `2019-01-01` have 3 instead of 14.

Please help.

Comment: What are you piping to `mutate`? It's the data, yes, but it's missing from the code.

Comment: Just use `summarise` instead of `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [Cumulative sum from a month ago until the current day for all the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973512/cumulative-sum-from-a-month-ago-until-the-current-day-for-all-the-rows?rq=1)
adapting the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data <- data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(sum_6m = map_dbl(1:n(), ~ sum(x[(date>= (date[.] - months(5))) &
                                                   (date<= date[.])], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: I think your code is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Using the classic way to **aggregate datasets** `x ~ id` by a function like `sum` with a `normal data.frame filter` it could be the following code.

### Code

```
library(lubridate)

# Define your data
data <- 
"id date x
1 2019-01-01 3
1 2018-12-01 4
1 2017-11-01 1
1 2017-10-01 2
1 2018-02-12 2
1 2017-09-01 2
"
# Read the table 
tab <- read.csv(text=data, header = T, sep=' ')

# Find the youngest date
top.date <- as.Date(max(tab$date))

# Calculate the threshold (before and after point) of 6 month
thresh   <- top.date) %m-% months(6)

# Calculate the sums over the ID's after the point date
after.thresh  <- aggregate(x ~ id, 
                           data = tab[as.Date(tab$date) >= thresh,], 
                           FUN  = sum)

# Calculate the sums over the ID's before the point date
before.thresh <- aggregate(x ~ id, 
                           data = tab[as.Date(tab$date) < thresh,], 
                           FUN=sum)

# Print the dates 
cat("TOP.DATE.IS:", format_ISO8601(top.date),
    " THRESH.DATE.IS:", format_ISO8601(thresh),"\n")

# Print the sums 
cat("SUM.BEFORE.THRESH:", after.thresh$x, 
    "SUM.AFTER.THRESH:", before.thresh$x,"\n")
```

### Results

```
TOP.DATE.IS: 2019-01-01  THRESH.DATE.IS: 2018-07-01 
SUM.BEFORE.THRESH: 7 SUM.AFTER.THRESH: 7
```